# Как называется программа CLI конвертер RTF в DOC(X)?

Tags: ms-word, doc, docx, rtf

Как называется программа конвертер RTF в DOC(X) с командной строкой?

rtf2doc ./file.rtf ./file.doc

Желательно под windows.

Comment: Да тех программ как грязи - Гугель по запросам `rtf2doc` и `rtf2docx` просто захлёбывается ссылками...

Comment: @Akina мне нужна CLI-программа, а не онлайн-конвертер, которых действительно как грязи.

Comment: А я и говорю о CLI-программах. Ну возьмите, например. IBM-овскую RTF2XML...

Comment: @Akina XSLT файл для конвертации XML в DOCX я не успею написать((( это через чур трудоемкая и малополезная программа.

Comment: Зачем Вы задаёте вопросы, если не намерены читать ответы? Цитирую: _The **rtf2xml** utility is a stand-alone migration utility that must be run on the application database after the application is upgraded. **The utility is provided to migrate the .RTF DOCUMENTS TO .DOCX**._

Comment: @Akina Вы похоже на своей волне. Откуда Вы цитируете совсем не понятно. Вышеупомянутую утилиту я нашел на sourceforge.net. А упоминание об этой утилиты — на странице http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en//SSAT72/com.ibm.help.empinstall_migrating.doc/Migration/c_RTFContractsToDOCMigration.html И пока не ясно зачем нужен Emptoris Contract Management application и откуда его брать.

Comment: http://github.com/tobya/DocTo/

Answer (score 0):

'Convert Doc' Command Line

NOTE: 'Convert Doc' can be used simply with the graphical user interface (GUI).  If you've never heard of 'Command Line' before, we would recommend not reading this section and instead download and try the software. 
'Convert Doc' can be run without a user interface with command line arguments much like in the good old DOS days.  Alternatively you can initiate command line execution by going to the operating systems 'command prompt' or within Windows at the START-RUN menu and typing it in there.  Lastly, the command line interface can be used from Batch files (files with *.BAT extension). 
There are two approaches to doing the command line:
A)  Specify a 'Conversion Job' that was built using the graphical user interface (GUI)
B)   Specify a 'Conversion Task' in detail

http://www.softinterface.com/Convert-Doc/Features/Convert-RTF-To-DOCX.htm